# Is it possible to have two distinct video outputs or add a second HDMI port?

Tags: hdmi, video, output

Is it possible to have two distinct video outputs or add a second HDMI port to the Raspberry Pi 2?

I need to output two different programs on two different screens

Comment: Hello and welcome. I don't think that there is a port with enough bandwith available to support a second HDMI port on the Pi. It might be possible to get an USB graphics card with limited resolution going. I think that I once read something like that around here... just cannot find it right now.